# 美しくつくろい飾ること　This　つくろい's meaning

Tags: meaning

I searched 修飾's meaning and it described "美しくつくろい飾ること"

I know what 美しく's meaning but I don't know つくろい. Can anyone explain it ?
[image]

^ Picture here

Answer (score 5):

As you know, I hope, all verbs and adjectives conjugate in Japanese.

「つくろ**い**」 is the 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") of the verb 「つくろ**う**/繕{つくろ}う」.

Thus, 「つくろ**い**飾{かざ}る」＝「つくろう」+「飾る」

「つくろう」 means "to repair" and 「飾る」, "to decorate".  So, 「つくろ**い**飾る」 means "to beautify", "to embellish", etc.

「つくろ**い**飾る」 is a compound verb and that is why the first verb is in its 連用形.  You just ***cannot*** say 「つくろ**う**飾る」.

Extra Info： There was an enormously successful advertising copy for a supermarket chain in the early 80's, which read:

「つくりながら、つくろいながら、くつろいでいる。」

It was all in kana because they wanted you to appreciate the **phonetic flow** of it.  Using Kanji for the three verbs would have destroyed that purpose.  It was created by 林真理子{はやしまりこ} in case any of you are fans.

Comment: Thank you very much !! I am very confused by this 繕う why it has to be in kana. Can you explain me more ? I think つくろう has its kanji but why Japanese choose to use hiragana ? Anyway thank you very much